# Dreamweaver cs5 (or cs 5.5) auto close (curly) parenthesis for PHP and CSS

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I'm new to dreamweaver, and I couldn't find a solution to this simple question.

Is this possible to auto close parenthesis and curly parenthesis in DW while coding PHP?

I mean, If I type this:

```
if (
```

I want to autoclose to this:

```
if ()
```

Or if I type this:

```
if () {
```

I want it to autoclose to this:

```
if () {}
```

Like PHPDesigner does.

Is that possible ? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a feature Dreamweaver offers, although Mac OS X users can install [AutoPairs](http://www.jwwalker.com/pages/autopairs.html) which does this automatically, on a per-application basis.

Comment: Sadly I'm working on windows environment. I will look for similar windows equivalents of autopairs. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[**Aptana**](http://www.aptana.com/) is an open source solution to Dreamweaver, which does this for you.

Comment: Thanks, Now I'm using linux on work station, and sublime text as default editor and komodo edit as alternative editor. Aptana was slow and it gave me many java errors, and those were due to localisation which I did not have access to.